# docker-compose Odoo 13 enterprise edition

Tags: docker-compose, odoo-13

I want to install odoo 13 enterprise edition with docker compose
But i don't know where to find a docker image of odoo 13 enterprise edition

> it should be noted that I have my odoo enterprise edition activation code

here is my docker-compose.yml code

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
    restart: always             # run as a service  

  odoo11:
    image: odoo:11.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8070:8069"
    tty: true
    command: -- --dev=reload
#    command: odoo scaffold /mnt/extra-addons/test_module
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    restart: always             # run as a service
```

this installed me, odoo 13 community not enterprise edition

Comment: Hi @ferdinand christian Fotie, did you solve the problem of how can install Enterprise edition with docker. Please share if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is documented here : https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/odoo/

Taken from the documentation, simplest configuration

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

Comment: I saw this link, and it only installs me the Enterprise version

Comment: @ferdinandchristianFotie yeah you wanted the same right? in your question "**this installed me, odoo 13 community not enterprise edition**"